# How can i use the value that is fetched from other page

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I want to use the value that is fetched from the other page and fed into a constructor. I have tried but its giving error as `only static member can be accessed in  initializers`. Could any one please let me know how can i use the variable that is fetched from the other page. Or please let me know if there is a way where i can fetch the details ie the user phone number from firebase and assign it to globalNumber
This is my code . The variable name is globalNumber

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

var globalNumber;
bool valueExist;

class Pricepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PricepageState createState() => _PricepageState();
}

class _PricepageState extends State<Pricepage> {

  var globalNumber;

  _PricepageState({this.globalNumber});
  StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> subscription;
  final DocumentReference documentReference =
  Firestore.instance.document("users/$globalNumber"); // (Here this value comes from the previous page this is just the phonenumber of the user from firebase auth)

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    subscription = documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.data.containsValue("true")) {
        setState(() {
          valueExist = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          valueExist = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: getPrice(),


      ),
    );
  }

  Widget getPrice() {
    try {
      if (valueExist) {
        return Text('Prices are visibile');
      }

      else {
        return Text('Verify first');
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer 2.0**

The major issue is with this line:

```
final DocumentReference documentReference =
  Firestore.instance.document("users/$globalNumber");
```

> You should not initialize your `final variable` outside the `initState()`. You need to do it inside the `initState()` only. That is why you are getting this error. As in your error only says ***only static member can be accessed in  initializers***. And your `static` member is `documentReference` only, which has to be initialized inside the `initializers`, which is in our case is our `initState()`

**This should work**

```
class _PricepageState extends State<Pricepage> {

  var globalNumber;

  _PricepageState({this.globalNumber});
  StreamSubscription<DocumentSnapshot> subscription;
  final DocumentReference documentReference;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    // initialise the value here
    documentReference = Firestore.instance.document("users/$globalNumber"); // (Here this value comes from the previous page this is just the phonenumber of the user from firebase auth)

    subscription = documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.data.containsValue("true")) {
        setState(() {
          valueExist = true;
        });
      }
      else {
        setState(() {
          valueExist = false;
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Rest code will remain the same.

Comment: But where will i place the conditions then which is in the init state method... Could you please edit your answer and let me know the whole flow.

Comment: Which condition are you talking about @CodeTasy ? Did not get your question completely. I have written my answer aligning to the substance you have given in your question

Comment: I have edited my code anyway @CodeTasy Please see and let me know if that gives you any clarity?

Comment: If you check the init method there are conditions like if datasnapshot.data.containsValue("true").. Could you please chek

Comment: Hey @CodeTasy the answer is under **Answer 2.0** section only. Please see :)